# Is there any option available for writing custom code in hygraph?

Tags: headless-cms, hygraph

I'm using Hygraph Headless CMS. I have Brands Model, and each Brand has associated location with it. I want to get all the Brands which are in 5 kilometer radius.But Hygraph generates some queries automatically for each model. Im looking for some way so i can write my custom query for it.
Is there any option available for it?

I searched alot, but i did not find any help in this.